# download ics(outlook Calendar) file from my application?

Tags: android

Hi i am new to android.I need to download .ics file from mail attachment. I use intent filter in Manifest xml file. But it downloads all the files from my application.I need to download .ics file only.How it's possible???

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ics" />    
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer by using this

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/calendar" /> 
</intent-filter>
```